# Why are portable split air conditioners not common?

Tags: air-conditioning

You can put the outdoor unit on your balcony, the indoor unit on the floor inside and -- without any problematic install you have a much better (or one would think so at least!) than your usual portable AC unit.

Why are these units so rare, especially in North America? I have much better success finding them in the UK.

[image: A portable split AC unit]

Comment: The picture shows a split device which is not portable. There is a contrast in your headline saying "portables are not common" and the text saying the split ones are rare. Then you say "split ones - without problematic install", well you need a hole in the wall to put the tubes and cable, this is more effort than for a portable device.

Comment: This is definitely a portable device, the indoor unit has castors, the outdoor unit has a handle. Use it in the summer (likely taping off the sliding balcony door to seal it) and pack it away in the winter. No drilling needed!

Comment: Ah ok a portable split device! Perhaps you can make that a little more clear to avoid misunderstandings for others :-) Well a problem of these is you have to leave the door open to lead the tube from inside to outside.

Comment: Window and balcony door kits for much large hoses of traditional portable ACs are a thing so that's not a problem, really.

Comment: There’s a huge difference between portable ones and portable-split ones. Portable ones( with one outlet hose) pump out the indoor air out making out side air seep in, which is again hotter. While the portable-split ones don’t have this problem. In addition, instead of having a 20 cm hole, you just have to have a 4 cm hole! I’m looking for these in Australia and can’t find any!!!!!

Comment: the US likes double hung windows, which are perfect for window ACs.

Comment: @dandavis What does double hung have to do with anything? Single hung ones take window AC units too, since the bottom sash is always a movable one.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much of a catch but houses in UK are so rarely specified with AC (only needed 3 days a year .. :) ) that there is a (small) market for the portable ones.

Houses in US have AC included in the build so often that it is almost standard - older housing stock may get upgrades.

Remember the refrigeration cycle used is only relatively recent compared to the time we have been building houses.

Thise portable units can work very nicely but making sure that the air volume is controlled is important otherwise you can end up trying to cool the atmosphere... ie windows shut etc

Comment: Keep in mind much of Europe got a "housing reset" courtesy of Junkers, Focke-Wulf, Avro and Consolidated.

Comment: @Harper "Much"? really? most housing stock in the UK survived - some places like Coventry were hit hard, but if you visit then you would be surprised at how much is pre-war. As for Europe, again some cities / towns never saw much while others... wel Guernica bombing was effective - when used properly...